# Getting parts of two classes to interact with a random chance?

Tags: ruby

I know I'm asking a lot of questions, and I apologize for that.

I am trying to get 2 classes to interact with each other, but with a random chance.

```
class Hands 
  attr_reader :name, :element, :skill, :mana, :health, :attack, :fire, :water, :lyfe, :summons
  attr_writer :mana, :health
  attr_accessor :summon

  def initialize(name, element, skill)
    @mana = 100
    @health = 200
    @summons = []
    @name = name
    @element = element
    @skill = skill
  end

 
  def summon
    @summons << summon
    random_number = [1, 2].sample
      if @element == "Lyfe"
        if random_number == 1
          puts "#{@name} summoned #{summon1.name}"
        elsif random_number == 2
          puts "#{@name} summoned #{summon2.name}"
      else
          puts "#{@name} can not use this ability!"
        end
      end
  end
end

class Summons
  attr_reader :name, :strength, :health
  attr_writer :name, :strength, :health
  attr_accessor :summon
  
  def initialize(name, strength)
    @name = name
    @strength = strength
      if @strength == "1"
      @health = 25
      @mana = 25
      elsif @strength == "2"
      @health = 50
      @mana = 50
      elsif @strength == "3"
      @health = 100
      @mana = 75
      end
  end
end
  
player1 = Hands.new('Silk', 'Lyfe', 'Summon')
player2 = Hands.new('Nubz', 'Lyfe', 'Manipulate Wildlife')
player3 = Hands.new('Lisk', 'Water', 'Invisible')
player4 = Hands.new('Azzi', 'Water', 'Manipulate Water')
player5 = Hands.new('Zeph', 'Fire', 'Lightning')
player6 = Hands.new('Ford', 'Fire', 'Manipulate Fire')
player7 = Hands.new('Boyd', 'Fire', 'Craft')
summon1 = Summons.new('Berto',  '1')
summon2 = Summons.new('Wicket',  '1')
summon3 = Summons.new('Skye',  '1')
summon4 = Summons.new('Test4',  '2')
summon5 = Summons.new('Test5',  '2')
summon6 = Summons.new('Test6',  '3')

player1.summon
```

I know I probably have some unnecessary code in there.
I am trying to get one of the players (Hands class) to randomly "summon" one of the summons. I tried using a random_number.sample command, but I got a stack level too deep error. The random_number code is shortened to 1 & 2 for testing purposes, but if it can somehow work and expand to all 6 that would be great.
Any explanation would help!

Comment: It doesn't get to the random number generation. The very first line of method `summon` is: `@summons << summon`. See the recursive call?

Comment: And I see at least one more problem down the line: this method won't be able to use local variables `summon1` and `summon2`, defined outside of the class. One way to solve this is to put all summonable things in an array inside of `Hands`.

Comment: Please make sure to construct a [mre]. Note that all three of those words are important: it should be an *example* only, you should not post your entire actual code, rather you should create a simplified example that demonstrates your problem. Also, it should be *minimal*, i.e. it should not contain anything that is not absolutely required to demonstrate the problem. (Most beginner problems can be demonstrated in less than 5 short simple lines of code.) And it should be *reproducible*, which means that if I copy&paste and run the code, I should see the exact same problem you see.

Answer (score 0):

> I got a stack level too deep error

That's because you call `summon` from within `summon`:

```
def summon           # <--+
  @summons << summon #    |
  #           ^^^^^^------+ invokes itself over and over again
```

But let's start from the beginning. The `Player#summon` method needs to somehow access the "summons".

You could create an array of available summons, e.g.

```
available_summons = [
  Summons.new('Berto',  '1'),
  Summons.new('Wicket',  '1'),
  Summons.new('Skye',  '1')
]
```

And then *pass* that array to your `summon` method:

```
player1 = Hands.new('Silk', 'Lyfe', 'Summon')
player1.summon(available_summons)
```

Within your method you would sample from that array and add the sampled element to the player's `@summons` array: (I removed any additional logic for now)

```
def summon(available_summons)
  summon = available_summons.sample
  @summons << summon
  puts "#{@name} summoned #{summon.name}"
end
```

Example with output:

```
player1 = Hands.new('Silk', 'Lyfe', 'Summon')

player1.summon(summons)
# Silk summoned Berto
player1.summon(summons)
# Silk summoned Skye
```

The `@summons` array will be populated as expected:

```
player1.summons
#=> [
#     #<Summons:0x00007fbf1c9d80b8 @name="Berto", @strength="1", @health=25, @mana=25>,
#     #<Summons:0x00007fbf1c9189c0 @name="Skye", @strength="1", @health=25, @mana=25>
#   ]
```

Note that passing the array to `Player#summon` is just *one* possible solution. You could also pass it to `Player.new` (i.e. `initialize`) and store it in an instance variable. Or – if the array is rather static – you could store it right within the `Player` class, maybe in a constant. It really depends on how you want to structure your code.